# Getting Error like "java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called"

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-data-jpa

I am migrating Spring XML based configuration to Java based configuration. The below class which implements **HttpSessionListener** and **ApplicationContextAware** was working fine with XML configuration. But with Java configuration, getting below error while starting the Tomcat server.

**Error:**

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'sessionListener' defined in com.grc.config.WebConfig: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Section 4.4 of the Servlet 3.0 specification does not permit this method to be called from a ServletContextListener that was not defined in web.xml, a web-fragment.xml file nor annotated with @WebListener
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:584)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:498)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:846)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:863)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:546)
```

**Class:**

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener,ApplicationContextAware {

    private static final Logger logger = ExtendedLoggerFactory.getLogger(Info.HTTP_LOGGER);

    @Autowired
    private JdbcHSqlRepository jdbcHSqlRepository;

    @Autowired
    private LoginEventRepository loginEventRepo;

    @SuppressWarnings("unused") 
    private ApplicationContext applicationContext;

    @Override 
    public void setApplicationContext(ApplicationContext applicationContext) throws BeansException { 
        this.applicationContext = applicationContext;

        if(applicationContext instanceof WebApplicationContext) {
            ((WebApplicationContext)applicationContext).getServletContext().addListener(this); 
        } 
    }

    @Override 
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        httpSessionEvent.getSession().setMaxInactiveInterval(5*60); 
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        HttpSession httpSession = httpSessionEvent.getSession();

        //mark user login event as looged out
        LoginEventVO event = (LoginEventVO)httpSession.getAttribute(Constants.LOGIN_EVENT);
        if(event != null) {
            event.setActive(false);

            loginEventRepo.saveAndFlush(event.transform());
        }

        logger.debug("Session destroyed : " + httpSession.getId());
        jdbcHSqlRepository.dropSessionTables(httpSession);
    }
}
```

When I tried without implementing **ApplicationContextAware**, able to start the server without any error, but getting below error when sessionDestroyed method is executed.

Error:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at com.grc.riskanalysis.interceptor.SessionListener.sessionDestroyed(SessionListener.java:45)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.expire(StandardSession.java:801)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.StandardSession.isValid(StandardSession.java:659)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.processExpires(ManagerBase.java:573)
    at org.apache.catalina.session.ManagerBase.backgroundProcess(ManagerBase.java:558)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.backgroundProcess(StandardContext.java:5474)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1398)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1402)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1370)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Is there anything I missed out with Java configuration?

After @lucid inputs, manually injected required dependencies in sessionDestroyed() method and it worked fine.

```
@Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent httpSessionEvent) {
        HttpSession httpSession = httpSessionEvent.getSession();

        //mark user login event as looged out
        LoginEventVO event = (LoginEventVO)httpSession.getAttribute(Constants.LOGIN_EVENT);
        ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.
                getWebApplicationContext(httpSession.getServletContext());
        if(event != null) {
            event.setActive(false);
            if(loginEventRepo == null) {
                this.loginEventRepo = (LoginEventRepository) 
                        ctx.getBean("loginEventRepository");
            }
            loginEventRepo.saveAndFlush(event.transform());
        }

        logger.debug("Session destroyed : " + httpSession.getId());
        if(jdbcHSqlRepository == null) {
            this.jdbcHSqlRepository = (JdbcHSqlRepository) 
                    ctx.getBean("jdbcHSqlRepository");
        }

        jdbcHSqlRepository.dropSessionTables(httpSession);
    }
```

Comment: is this spring boot application @Ram

Comment: @lucid, it is not spring boot application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can register `HttpSessionListener` in your application like this.

Remove `ApplicationContextAware` implementation and related methods

```
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  // keep required code
}
```

Now, we can use `@WebListener` annotation to register and add `@ServletComponentScan` to the main class. (in case spring boot app)

```
@Weblistener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {
  // keep required code
}
```

In Non-Springboot Application, configure like this.

```
public class AnnotationWebAppInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

@Override
public void onStartup(ServletContext container) throws ServletException {
    // other configs

    container.addListener(SessionListener.class);

    // other configs
}
```

```
 As this is not spring managed bean, we need to manually inject dependencies. (make sure bean names are correct)

@Weblistener
public class SessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    private LoginEventRepository loginEventRepo;

    private JdbcHSqlRepository getJdbcHSqlRepository(HttpSessionEvent evt){
      if(loginEventRepo != null) {
         ApplicationContext ctx = WebApplicationContextUtils.
             getWebApplicationContext(evt.getServletContext());

         this.loginEventRepo = (LoginEventRepository) 
                            ctx.getBean("loginEventRepo");
      }
      return this.loginEventRepo;
    }
}
```

Comment: tried your proposed solution, but getting the exception when session destroyed method is called as I mentioned in problem description. But only difference is, thrown same exception thrown twice.

Comment: Can you tell me which line throwing NPE in ur code @Ram

Comment: I have updated your answer with code where throwing the NPE . JPA repository objects are not being created here.

Comment: @Ram should work now, updated my answer. In case, you need to add more details to question, plz update question.

Comment: I will try and let you know. Thanks

Comment: In SessionListener class itself (sessionDestroyed() method), manually injected dependencies and worked fine. I will update my question with working code. Thanks @lucid